# Django Authentication system modifications

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-authentication

I am new to Django Authentication system and I am unable to find the correct debugging method.

I want to create a function to handle login requests and I have done the necessary steps to do the same.

1. created a login url path in main project URLS.py file.

   ```
    path('members/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),
   ```
2. created a login url in members app to point to a function created in views.py

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login_user, name='login'),]
   ```
3. defined what to do when user comes to specific url

   ```
   def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('-'*100)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ("You are now logged in"))
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.success(request, ("Invalid credentials"))
            return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'registration/Login.html')
   ```
4. I have created a Login Page in templates folder.

   ```
   {% extends 'Base.html'%}
   {% block title %}
        Login to the Blog Page
    {% endblock %}
   {% block content%}
   <h1>Members Login</h1>
   <div class="form-group">

    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">User Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "username">
            <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with 
   anyone else.</div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
          </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
     </form>
    <br>
    </div>
   {% endblock %}
   ```

Now when I get to the /members/login after submitting the user details the print statement in post method is not printed in the console. So I am suspecting that the post request is not being redirected to the login_user function. Can anyone help me out to identify why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Djnago will fire the view that it first finds for the path `members/login`, and that is the login view of the `django.contrib.auth` module. You can swap the order of the views to visit the `login` view of your view:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('members/', include('members.urls')),  # 🖘 `members.urls first
    path('members/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

But it might be better to give your view a different path, to prevent any confusion.

Comment: @Sunderam I didn't get you!